# Script to display the URL column Data with Alias names in Spotfire

Tags: ironpython, spotfire

Can someone please help me with the below Scenario:
I have two Columns in my Data Table : 1) ID Number 2) ID URL (Which consists of URL to the ID Number).
I need Script to display the ID Number as hyperlink so that when clicked it redirects to the respective ID URL. (The last 10-14 Digits of the URL consists of the ID Number).
I Dont want this to be done through property Settings, since the data is being pulled from a Streaming file through a link.

Please hint me with some Ideas. Also, please let me know if you need any clarification with my ask.

Answer (score 1):

@Ch3 - As you didn't provide an example of the URL, I am assuming that the domain name remains the same and only the ID numbers at the end of the URL are changing.

One solution for this is rendering your ID column as a Link. Here is the screenshot as how it is done.

Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: Hi @ksp585 . Sorry but this is done through Property Settings. I am aware of this solution. But can't implement, since my Data is being loaded from streaming files. There are 5 Files that will be loaded, based on the selection from Dropdown. The Domain URL's for the 5 Files are  Different. So i need a script that will help me to do this.  So, when the data is loaded on web player, the ID Number column is shown as hyperlink. Thanks.